# Searchview in Android doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, searchview

I'm pretty new to java and android development and i have been working on an app for a school project in which I want an actionbar with SearchView. I have looked at all examples but I cannot get it to work. I have searched but nothing helpfull has come my way.

**The problem is:** I open the SearchView and type in my search query, but after that nothing happens at all.

my `pdLoading` message is not even showing after having entered the query and click search.

So Can any of you help me? This project is very important to me.
So here is my code:

Thanks in advance :D

**search.java**

```
package com.example.adek002319.brinkshopping;

import ...


public class search extends AppCompatActivity {

// CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private RecyclerView mRVFish;
private searchapp mAdapter;

SearchView searchView = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // adds item to action bar
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_main, menu);

    // Get Search item from action bar and Get Search service
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) search.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if (searchItem != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    }
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), search.class)));
        searchView.setIconified(false);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// Every time when you press search button on keypad an Activity is recreated which in turn calls this function
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Get search query and create object of class AsyncFetch
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.clearFocus();
        }
        new AsyncFetch(query).execute();

    }
}

// Create class AsyncFetch
private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(search.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;
    String searchQuery;

    public AsyncFetch(String searchQuery){
        this.searchQuery=searchQuery;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your php file resides
            url = new URL("http://192.168.1.5/Android/searchforapp.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // setDoInput and setDoOutput to true as we send and recieve data
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // add parameter to our above url
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("searchQuery", searchQuery);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {
                return("Connection error");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.dismiss();
        List<DataSearch> data=new ArrayList<>();

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if(result.equals("no rows")) {
            Toast.makeText(search.this, "No Results found for entered query", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{

            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    DataSearch searchData = new DataSearch();
                    searchData.Productnaam = json_data.getString("productnaam");
                    searchData.Productprijs = json_data.getInt("productprijs");
                    searchData.Productretailer = json_data.getString("productretailer");
                    searchData.Description = json_data.getString("descripton");
                    data.add(searchData);
                }

                // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
                mRVFish = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.prijslijst);
                mAdapter = new searchapp(search.this, data);
                mRVFish.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mRVFish.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(search.this));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // You to understand what actually error is and handle it appropriately
                Toast.makeText(search.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(search.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

**activity_search.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>



<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/prijslijst"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:ignore="InefficientWeight" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**DataSearch.java**

```
package com.example.adek002319.brinkshopping;

public class DataSearch {

public String Productnaam;
public int Productprijs;
public String Productretailer;
public String  Description;
}
```

**searchapp.java**

```
package com.example.adek002319.brinkshopping;

import ...

public class searchapp extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<DataSearch> data= Collections.emptyList();
DataSearch current;

// create constructor to initialize context and data sent from MainActivity
public searchapp(Context context, List<DataSearch> data){
    this.context=context;
    inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
}

// Inflate the layout when ViewHolder created
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search2, parent,false);
    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // Get current position of item in RecyclerView to bind data and assign values from list
    MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
    DataSearch current=data.get(position);
    myHolder.textProductnaam.setText(current.Productnaam);
    myHolder.textPrijs.setText("Prijs " + current.Productprijs);
    myHolder.textRetailer.setText("Retailer: " + current.Productretailer);
    myHolder.textDescription.setText("Description: " + current.Description);
    myHolder.textPrijs.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView textProductnaam;
    TextView textPrijs;
    TextView textRetailer;
    TextView textDescription;

    // create constructor to get widget reference
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textProductnaam= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textProductnaam);
        textPrijs = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPrijs);
        textRetailer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textRetailer);
        textDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDescription);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked an item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**activity_search2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_search2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.adek002319.brinkshopping.searchapp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="fish name"
    android:id="@+id/textProductnaam"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="price"
    android:id="@+id/textPrijs"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/textDescription"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/textProductnaam"
    android:textColor="#666"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="sd"
    android:id="@+id/textRetailer"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/textDescription"
    android:textColor="#666"/>
```

**AnroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.adek002319.brinkshopping">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



    <activity android:name=".search" android:launchMode="singleTop"><intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".search" />
</intent-filter></activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".recentitems" />
    <activity android:name=".FavoriteActivity" />

    <activity android:name=".searchapp"/> //i also get an error here that says searchapp has no default constuctor
</application>
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here. Can you make it a [mcve], please?

Comment: I don't really know where the error is or where in my code it goes wrong. But I have just removed some unnecessary code....

Comment: Does the Asynctask work? Did you test that independently?

Comment: `searchapp` is not an Activity, so I don't know why you added it to the manifest as one. Adapters don't need added to the manifest

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm very new to this. How do I test Asynctask? And yes I see that now that searchapp is not an activity I've removed that now.

Comment: For example, you could use a simple edittext, and a button, and your recyclerview. You click the button, it takes the text from the edittext, and executes the asynctask to populate the list. Once you get that working, then you can try a searchview.

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the help. My asynctask works. The problem was in my manifestfile. Instead of adding this '`meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />` to the `<activity android:name=".search" android:launchMode="singleTop">` , I added this `<meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".search" />`